# MATLAB interface with QEMU

Tags: c, matlab, embedded, stm32, qemu

I'm trying to develop a custom machine in QEMU and kind of successful in doing so. Now I want to build a  module that can communicate with QEMU to provide some inputs to QEMU and interact with it.

I have chosen MATLAB to build a model that interfaces with my custom machine in QEMU. I know MATLAB has **Embedded coder interface and QEMU add on** that runs QEMU as third party software internally(downloads the QEMU itself).

But since I have customized QEMU for my machine, how do I interface MATLAB with custom QEMU?

I thought it would be something like running QEMU as

`qemu-system-arm -machine x -s -S -kernel x.elf` so that when I run QEMU with `-s` it listens on a port and communicate with other modules. Is this possible with MATLAB? Or is there any other way?

Comment: Is there doco for the QEMU add-on? All I found was this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/armcortexm/ref/getqemuemulatoraddon.html?searchHighlight=QEMU. Worst case, lots of Matlab stuff is written in M-code and the source is visible. You can open up the Embedded Coder functions and read their source code.